# I want to update my branch with the new files/code a team member added to their branch; do I use Merge, Pull, or Rebase?

Tags: git

(Using git through IntelliJ, not command line)

I'm newish to git and I've been reading up on it and learning as much as I can, but I cannot seem to find a clear cut answer to this question.

I'm working in a team where each member has their own branch under origin (I'll call them `FredBranch`, `JoeBranch`, and `MindyBranch` - I'll call my branch `MyBranch` for simplicity). Fred did a bunch of work and added all kinds of files to the project under his branch. Now I'm going to do some work but I want those files in my branch so I'm working with the newest version of the project. Fred said he pushed the changes onto his branch.

If I right-click FredBranch under my Remote branches section, it gives me the following options:

- `Rebase 'MyBranch' onto origin/FredBranch`
- `Merge origin/FredBranch into 'MyBranch'`
- `Pull into 'MyBranch' Using Rebase`
- `Pull into 'MyBranch' Using Merge`

I can't seem to wrap my head around the differences, or at least how they apply to this specific situation haha. What would be the correct thing to do here?

Comment: it's actually a good question. writing an answer...

Comment: My assumption is that options 1/3 and 2/4 are nearly identical, except for the extra fetch that a pull does. That leaves you with the choice of whether to merge or rebase...

Comment: added my answer. it got a bit longer than I expected but hopefully it gives you an idea.

Comment: This branching strategy is not particularly Git-friendly and will **definitely** lead to problems with regressions and having difficulty knowing what the current production "source of truth" is. Look at common Git branching patterns -- GitHubFlow is a very good, simple approach that will probably be less confusing and require fewer steps to keep people synchronized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rebasing** makes your branch contain all the commits from the other branch while also putting your commits specific in your own branch on *top* of the branch you're rebasing onto. The git history becomes one as if you started your work from the rebased branch, that's why the word "rebase", basing your work again.

**Merging** achieves the same thing as rebasing but it creates a merge commit while keeping both branches' history.

**Pulling** is fetch + merge. So, you refresh your origin, and then merge a remote branch onto your local branch.

---

Now, let's take an example. Let's assume:

`MyBranch` contains:

```
My Commit A
develop(common branch)'s lastest commit
```

`FredBranch` contains:

```
Fred Commit A
develop(common branch)'s lastest commit
```

If you rebase your branch onto `FredBranch`, the new git tree will be:

```
My Commit A
Fred Commit A
develop(common branch)'s lastest commit
```

If you merge `FredBranch` into your branch:

```
Merge FredBranch into HEAD (some auto-generated commit message)
|                   \
|                   |
My Commit A     Fred Commit A
develop(common branch)'s lastest commit
```

Pull is basically the same thing as merge, so creates the same git tree.

---

Re: 4 options,

**Rebase 'MyBranch' onto origin/FredBranch**: this simply means you're rebasing your `MyBranch` branch onto the *remote* `FredBranch`.

**Merge origin/FredBranch into 'MyBranch'**: merging the *remote* `FredBranch` into your local `MyBranch` branch.

**Pull into 'MyBranch' Using Rebase**: this is basically a rebase (same as #1). The only difference is it first fetches the remote (i.e. refreshes it).

**Pull into 'MyBranch' Using Merge**: This is pull that we discussed in the first section of this answer. Same as #2 but as you may know by now, this also fetches the remote.

---

Now, back to your question. So, which is the best option?

This is a bit opinion-based so I won't tell you what I think is the best option. I'll just share what are the options and most common practices.

Usually, rebasing is done when you're working with a common branch (`develop`, `main`, etc), and also it involves trickier conflict resolution process, so it's not common to do it between two working branches. But if you want, you can do it with this option: `Rebase 'MyBranch' onto origin/FredBranch`.

The most common practice for merging two WIP feature branches is merging. You have two options of merging:

- Using `Merge origin/FredBranch into 'MyBranch'` option, i.e. merging the remote branch directly into your local working branch.
- Create a local copy of `FredBranch` and then merging the local `FredBranch` into your working branch.

Pull is not a new concept. It confuses people and I don't love the term. You can always think of pull as a merge. It's basically the same thing. Pull just fetches the remote, and then merge a certain branch onto your local branch. So, my advice is always fetch whenever possible, don't use pull but instead, use merge or reset HEAD.

Comment: Technically, `git pull` runs `git fetch` and then some other command of your choice (`git pull --rebase` runs `git rebase`, `git pull --ff-only` runs `git merge --ff-only`, etc.). But yes. :-)

Comment: yeah, that makes `pull` even more confusing. it's a "smart" command and smart is not always good.